# User authentication in Vault

Tags: authentication, hashicorp-vault

We are using vault to store service configurations and have those services fetch those configuration at deploy time through our CI/CD pipeline. I have created several roles within vault that restrict access to different backends.

Now i want to allow some team members to be able to access vault through the UI so that they can modify/update those service configurations.

The different options i see

1. Use `username/password` option. Works fine but the problem i see is that all members will have to go through the vault admin to punch their passwords. We are a remote first team so that is not really an option. Even if we weren't i don't see how they could manage their own password (update it for example) without the admin being around.
2. There is the `github authentication` which requires a token. Not a very straightforward option for users who are not very familiar with github and token based authentication.
3. Finally, there is the AWS option (we are hosted on AWS) which we could use, I just don't see how i could use this one for user authentication in the vault UI.

Ideally, I would love to see a github authentication option where users use OAuth from github with username/password and 2fa enabled.

What options do I have to perform the flow i describe above?